# Changing an item in a custom UITableviewCell that is not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Suppose I have 10 items in my `UITableView` but only 4 items are being displayed at a time which changes when the user scrolls up or down. Now suppose I am on the 10th row so only the rows from 6->10 are being displayed. What should I do if I would like to change something on on the 2nd row.

Currently I have only 4 items and I am using the following approach

```
NSArray *cells = [tableView visibleCells];
for (CustomTableViewCell *cell in cells)
{
    if(cell.someproperty == 23)
    {
       //Show a certain image on the cell
       [cell.someButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

I realize the above approach probably wont work for items that are not being displayed (as those cells dont exist) because of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` being used. What options do I have any suggestions ?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just put the if statement logic in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Yes because cell 10 might be a reason for a change in cell 2. In `cellForrowAtIndexPath ` ill be under the same situation as as `indexpath.row` might be 10 and I would like to change something in second row

Comment: Could you create a property to hold a specific value that cell 10 would change? Then if cell 2's property equals the property you set, do your logic?

Comment: i could definitely do that but I was hoping there was a better (faster) way especially when a lot of cells would be changing row 10 might change row 2 row 8 might change row 9 and so on

Comment: In the case where the property can be different for each cell, I would create an `NSDictionary`. In that dictionary, your key would be an index path, and the value would be the value of the property that could change. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, find the value for the current index path. And when a value changes, run the logic on the `visibleCells` like you were doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change the value of non-visible cells. Non-visible cells actually don't exist, because of the way table views reuse cells (for performance). So you can mess with visible cells if you like, but for the ones that aren't currently visible you need to wait until they're made visible again with -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Another option may be to not modify the visible cells at all. Just call -reloadData and -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: handle the updated state.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change cell content if it is not displayed.
The content will be refreshed next time the UITableView will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of your `UITableViewDataSource`.
The content of  the cell rely on the **data**.

So, modify your data model to be able to know that something selected in row 10 change the state of row 2. Next time row 2 will be displayed, its change will be there.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

You just configure the `UITableViewCell` as it should appear, the system automatically calls your callback when the cell is visible.

Answer (score -1):

The best way I think is you have an object that the cell holds. And all objects are store in an Array. So your numberOfRowsInSection returns the count of your Array. Every time you scroll your table view it creates a new cell depends on the indexPath.row. So if you want to change the 2nd cell. You'll just need to modify the 2nd object inside your array. Example :

```
CellObject *cell_object = [YourArray objectAtIndex:2];
cell_object.cellImage = "Your_new_image";
```

And then on your tableView : cellForRowAtIndex

```
CellObject *cell_object = [YourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.image = cell_object.cellImage;
```

Comment: Table views don't work that way. They get reused. If you have six visible rows, then when you look at row 8 it's actually recycling what was row 1 just a moment ago. Trying to hold on to any of these views will prove futile.